# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n} - \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{n}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n} - \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{n}$$ convergent?

Comment: what does $\sqrt{-}$ mean?

Comment: I'd like to edit it, but cannot. It should be $\sqrt{n} - $. The correct formula is $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}-\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}{n}$.

Comment: why can't you edit it? I can do it for you

Comment: Have no idea..it's correct now, thanks!

Comment: Divergent: Comparison test.

Answer (score 3):

Hint
$$\frac{\sqrt{n} - \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{n}\geq\frac{\sqrt{n} -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n\sqrt{n}}\geq\frac{n-\frac{n}{2}}{n\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$